# voice recording until stopped

Tags: java, android, microphone, audiorecord

how can I record Voice BYTES through mic continuously until press the stop button, I used audio recorder but I keep saving them in the same buffer how can 
I make a buffer with variable size that will fit all the bytes and what is the fastest way to move the bytes from the temporary buffer (I read in every time ) to the final one?

```
ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
          AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT));

  buffersizebytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
          AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );

 ar.read(buffer, 0, buffersizebytes);
```

Comment: _"how can I make a buffer with variable size that will fit all the bytes?"_ That's probably not the best solution since you have a relatively limited amount of RAM available. Better to write the buffers to a file, and then read all the data back piece by piece if you need to do any post-processing.

Comment: ok but isn't that time consuming because I have to read the buffer write it byte by byte to file and then at processing again read it byte by byte? I wan the app to be as close it can to real time

Comment: You don't have to do the reading and writing byte by byte just because you're doing file I/O. As for the real time-requirement; something that needs the complete recording before it starts processing the data isn't going to be real time anyway (and if you don't need the complete recording before you start processing I don't see why you need to keep the buffers in the first place).